# automatic redirecting to base_url in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have not used redirect but even my page getting redirect automatically to home page. controller page:

```
             //print_r($data);
    $orderid = $this->Order_model->insert_order_detail();
    if($orderid){
        if ($cart = $this->cart->contents()){
        foreach ($cart as $item): 
        $order_detail = array(
                'order_id'      => $orderid,
                'product_id'    => $item['id'],
                'order_qty'         => $item['qty']

            );  
    $order_data = $this->Order_model->insert_order_data($order_detail);
    endforeach;
    }
    }

    $enscryptorder = $this->encryption->encrypt($orderid);
    redirect('billing/payment_mode');

   //-------herer page is redirecting to base not to billing controller
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for your redirect code

```
redirect(base_url().'billing/payment_mode');
```

Did you also manage your routes in your config?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, add a URL helper in your autoload config. After that it may be work for you.
 Thanks